# Convert Video to Audio in client side then upload it to backend to reduce uploading size

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, client-side, converters

In our project we only need the audio of a video file, to reduce the uploading size for a client I'm looking for a way to convert chosen video file to audio in clientside then try to upload the file to the backend.
It's a react app by the way.

Any idea or solution or library will help.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the audio track from the video is a conversion process that uses video/audio codecs and could take almost the same time as the video length itself to re-encode the streams.

It might be either a client application (downloaded on a user pc) or you have to upload the file to your backend, or to some online service that provides an [Online Converter from MP4 to MP3](https://conversiontools.io/convert/mp4-to-mp3) for example, this converter - https://conversiontools.io/convert/mp4-to-mp3. It has limitations for a free tier.

Check other links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17532410/4299666